# How to enter Advanced Boot Options menu on Windows 7 without bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader, grub2

I need a way to enter the Advanced Boot Options menu of Windows 7. The computer is dualbooting with Linux, so GRUB2 has taken the place of Windows bootloader. So pressing F8 on boot won't do anything.

I know there are several methods to do this on Windows 8 and 8.1 and 8.1.1.

**Method 1**

1. Bring up the Charm Bar on the right.
2. Click on Settings.
3. Click Change PC Settings.
4. Update and recovery (Windows 8.1).
5. Click Recovery.
6. Click Restart now under Advanced startup.

**Method 2**

1. Bring up the Charm Bar on the right.
2. Click on Settings.
3. Click on Power.
4. Hold Shift and click Restart.

**Method 3**

```
shutdown /r /o
```

But that option is not available on Windows 7.

**So as a Windows 7 user, what options *do I have*?**

Comment: Can't say for sure, but I'm pretty sure those Windows 8 options are for UEFI only. Depending on what you're trying to do, you might be able to pull it off by booting from the Windows 7 DVD though.

Comment: It looks like `msconfig.exe` could be the solution. I'm not sure though that all the options from the Advanced Boot Options menu are available there as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use GRUB, but with other bootloaders, you just press F8 just immediately after selecting the operating system.

Do this: press "Windows 7" in the bootloader and at the same time start pressing F8 very rapidly

Comment: OK, will try pressing F8 frantically. But just for the record, if not GRUB, then what other bootloader are you using?

Comment: This changed. You can try holding down **Ctrl** instead, but not  sure this will work without Windows' own bootloader.

Comment: @Mario On Windows 8 there is also **Shift+F8** but it has never worked for me, I think Windows 8 boots too quickly. That could be part of the reason why they revamped this mechanism in Windows 8 and included the `/o` option for the shutdown command.

Comment: @sammyg I'm using chameleon bootloader (not sure it can work with ext partitions)

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm