# How to make Windows 8 Show Advanced Startup On Boot?

Tags: windows-8, boot, reboot, uefi

I can't seem to find a way to do this, I already know how to initialize an advanced startup in Windows 8 and I have also gone through this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/752841/how-to-enter-advanced-boot-options-menu-on-windows-7-without-bootloader), but that's not what I want, I want the advanced startup screen to show up on boot instead of booting right into Windows then performing the steps to bring up advanced startup.

I have the need to do this cause dual-booting Ubuntu with my UEFI-based PC hasn't been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change your system to use legacy boot mode instead of standard boot mode. When this is enabled, the system will boot up just like earlier versions of Windows, which causes the OS list to show up just after the system turns on (on dual-boot PCs) and adds the ability to press and hold F8 to access advanced system options upon turning it on (on single-boot PCs). Here's how to do that:

Open an elevated command prompt in Windows and type:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

...to change it to legacy. To change it back to the standard method, type:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standard
```

Did that help?

Comment: Thanks, there's an issue with Windows 8 UEFI Pc's dual-booting with Ubuntu and having grub as the default boot manager, so my only chance of booting Ubuntu is by selecting to boot from the Ubuntu partition from advanced startup.

Comment: @Feyisayo Please try it and see if it works. If it did, you may accept this answer. If it didn't, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Okay, I tried the legacy way and got advanced options but I only have options to boot into safe mode, safe mode with command prompt etc but no options to boot from a device or drive.

Comment: @Feyisayo Seems like a problem with your UEFI then. You must press the required key at startup to get the UEFI menu to change the boot device order.